# How To Set All Text And Text Color Labels In A GroupBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, label, groupbox

How do you reset the Text and ForeColor of Labels in a GroupBox to a custom or default value?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a function that looks at each control in the groupbox and set it's value. Notice, you can modify any control in the groupbox.

```
        private void ResetLabelText(Control control)
        {
            List<Label> lbls = groupBox1.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList();
            foreach (var lbl in lbls)
            {
                lbl.Text = "...";
                lbl.ForeColor = default(Color);
            }
        }
```

The function can then be called from a button click like so.

```
        private void button4_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ResetLabelText(groupBox1);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Your ResetLabelText method ignores the control parameter.

Comment: `control.Controls.OfType<Label>().Select(c => c.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText).ToArray();`

Comment: Or `control.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList().ForEach(c => { c.ForeColor =  SystemColors.ControlText; c.Text = "..."; });`

Comment: Awesome!!! Thanks for the help, Jimi! Any extra information is appreciated.